# Generating cumulative sum of deal values for 3 year intervals

Tags: stata

Please note that this content has already been posted in statalist. Re-posted here beacuse link to my dta.file doesn't work in statalist. here's the link on that posting: 
http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/852325-generating-cumulative-sum-of-deal-values-for-3-year-intervals

I'm trying to generate cumulative sum of deal values (£ mn.) for acquisitions of target companies in an interval of 3 years prior to any acquisition announcement. I've tried using a similar code as given in Stata Journal (2007) 7: Events in intervals, but can't get desired result.

The code i've used to generate this sum (i'm not sure how to generate cumulative sum) as yr3_cum_dealval in an interval of 3 years:

```
gen yr3_cum_dealval = .
quietly forval i = 1/`= _N' {
sum (deal_value_mn) if lspdno == lspdno[`i'] & inrange(event_date[`i'] – event_date, 1, 1098)
replace yr3_cum_dealval = r(sum) in `i'
}
```

Here, deal_value_mn is the amount paid in £ mn. for each acquisition, lspdno is the unique id for each acquiring company, event_date date of announcement of each deal/acquisition, 1098 = 366*3 (3 years interval).

I don't understand in the column yr3_cum_dealval, why i always get '0' as starting deal value in the span of 3 years, when it should rather be the actual amount paid in the first acquisition, the sum of 1st deal amount and 2nd deal amount for the second acquisition, likewise the sum of first two amounts paid plus that paid for the 3rd in case of cumulative deal value for third acquisition (provided the first two acquisitions took place within 3 years of the third deal) and so on.
Also, when there were 2 acquisitions announced on the same date, the cumulative deal value for each of these dates should be different (i get same yr3_cum_dealval for 2 same date acquisitions), the 1st same date should have the sum of amounts paid for the prior 3 year deals as well as current deal amount, whereas the 2nd same date should have the first same event_date amount paid included in the cumulative sum with prior 3 year amounts, as well as the amount corresponding to the current acquisition.

I'm pasting dropbox link to dta.file with a snapshot of my data for just 1 company doing many acquisitions from year 1994 until 2006, where the column with name yr3_cum_dealval shows what i got using the above code, while Correct_yr3_cum_dealval shows what i need to get.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64545449/cumul_dealvalue_ranks.dta

Please help me to correct this code.

Thanks, Suparna Ray

Comment: You should give an explicit reference to http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/852325-generating-cumulative-sum-of-deal-values-for-3-year-intervals It's important for people to know that there has been discussion, not just a question, on this thread.

Comment: thanks for mentioning this - i've added a link to my statalist posting.

Comment: You are assuming that your date variable is a daily date variable. You should check that this is so. If you `summarize` your date variable, it should show a mean less than about 20,000. If you have a very different figure, it is something else.

Comment: Yes, my event_date variable is a daily date variable showing a mean of 15249.87 - sorry, i didn't quite understand how that would affect the code because i've used a similar code (not exactly) before to count number of prior acquisitions in an interval of 3 years & i had also used the same daily date variable there using the code you had given in Stata journal 7 - it worked perfectly, so why shouldn't it work here? Instead of counting number of prior deals, i'm just trying to generate cumulative sum of prior amounts paid with respect to each acquisition.

Comment: Because if your variable was really a date-time variable then 1098 would be 1098 milliseconds. Evidently that's not the problem.

Comment: If you `summarize` you get sums, not cumulative sums. Your restriction to date differences >= 1 rules out the current observation.

Comment: I didn't see any stata command that'd generate cumulative sum, 'cusum' command does different thing. How do i recode event_date difference then here? Thanks, for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant part of your sample data is given here together with another variable `wanted`. (Posting sample data directly like this is often more helpful than posting a link to a file.)

```
. l lspdno deal_value_mn event_date yr3 correct event_date wanted

      +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      | lspdno   deal_v~n   event_d~e   yr3_cu~l   correc~l   event_d~e   wanted |
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
   1. |    286      214.1   03oct1994          0      214.1   03oct1994    214.1 |
   2. |    286        100   11jul1995      214.1      314.1   11jul1995    314.1 |
   3. |    286      126.1   19oct1998          0      126.1   19oct1998    126.1 |
   4. |    286      214.1   01nov1999      126.1      340.2   01nov1999    340.2 |
   5. |    286      214.1   26may2000      340.2      554.3   26may2000    554.3 |
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
   6. |    286      214.1   06jul2000      554.3      768.4   06jul2000    768.4 |
   7. |    286        5.6   01aug2000      768.4        774   01aug2000      774 |
   8. |    286       58.4   04jul2002      647.9      492.2   04jul2002    706.3 |
   9. |    286      170.6   08oct2002      706.3      662.8   08oct2002    876.9 |
  10. |    286      214.1   31dec2002      662.8      876.9   31dec2002    876.9 |
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  11. |    286      214.1   22jul2004      443.1      657.2   22jul2004   1395.4 |
  12. |    286      738.2   22jul2004      443.1     1395.4   22jul2004   1395.4 |
  13. |    286      214.1   25sep2005       1337     1551.1   25sep2005   1551.1 |
  14. |    286      299.8   19may2006     1166.4     1466.2   19may2006   1680.3 |
  15. |    286      214.1   19may2006     1166.4     1680.3   19may2006   1680.3 |
      +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I see three confusions here:

First, as already indicated in comments, as you want to include the current transaction, your `inrange()` condition should be

```
   inrange(event_date[`i'] - event_date, 0, 1098)
```

N.B. 0 not 1.

Second, your indications of what is correct seem to be partly incorrect: in particular observations 11 and 12 are for the same date, as are 14 and 15. As I understand it, the values of the variable you want should therefore be the same, not different.

Third, you are thinking of this as a cumulative sum, but as least as far as Stata is concerned it's a sum in an interval and cumulative sum syntax is irrelevant. Note that the function (not command) `sum()` is what returns cumulative sums.

The variable `wanted` was calculated by

```
gen wanted = . 

quietly forval i = 1/`=_N' {
    sum (deal_value_mn) if lspdno == lspdno[`i'] & inrange(event_date[`i'] - event_date, 0, 1098)
    replace wanted = r(sum) in `i' 
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, Nick - i understand my incorrect codes now.out of the 3 points you've made, i'd want to point out in respect of the 2nd one that since amounts paid for 2 acquisitions on the same date are different, e.g. for observations 11 & 12, one amount = 214.1, whereas the other is 738.2, to my understanding the cumulative sum (although sum in intervals here) should be different. But the current code doesn't provide for it.

Comment: Sorry, but you've lost me. The code will treat observations for the same date in the same way; if that's not you want, then the code needs to be changed.

Comment: ... also your results will not be reproducible.

Comment: Do u mean that the code can't be changed in an effective manner just to change same cumulative sums of paid values on same date by same company, without disturbing the cumulative sums on different dates? Thanks for shwoing the data post - i'll remember to post my sample data next time the way you've shown.

Comment: Finished on http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/852325-generating-cumulative-sum-of-deal-values-for-3-year-intervals It gets complicated for all if you cross-post!